# Registering tests on QTest in CTest apart from executable like GTest realizations

Tags: qt, cmake, ctest, qtestlib, qtest

I have an executable with multiple tests written with **QTest**.
The executable is being registered using `add_tests(NAME test_name COMMAND test_executable)`. Obviously, tests will be handled as one in **CTest**, so it will be difficult to find the problem if one of the hundreds fails. It will be worse when new executables with tests are added.

Is it possible to register the tests separately like with GTest realizations? Is there an alternative to [GTEST_ADD_TESTS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/module/GoogleTest.html#command:gtest_add_tests) or [GTEST_DISCOVER_TESTS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/module/GoogleTest.html#command:gtest_discover_tests) CMake functions for QTest tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just with using **QTest** I didn't find a solution but tried a different approach that works.

I changed testing framework to **GTest**. But still, a test application is linked with **QTest** library for having access to such features as emulating GUI interaction.

The default *main* function from the *gtest_main* module may be not compatible because it is required require to initialize *QApplication* for many features of Qt. There is an implementation of *main* based on the **GTest**'s in the [gtest_main.cc](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/ff21b36e1e858bf9274ed2bbf4921e415363c393/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc) source file.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    printf("Running main() from %s\n", __FILE__);
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

After testing, I didn't find any problem as well as using [GTEST_ADD_TESTS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/module/GoogleTest.html#command:gtest_add_tests) or [GTEST_DISCOVER_TESTS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/module/GoogleTest.html#command:gtest_discover_tests) CMake functions.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) to [run](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#build-a-project) your tests.

```
add_custom_target(run_test qtest_executable_target)
```

```
cmake <dir>
cmake --build <dir> -t run_test
```

Comment: But it won't be integrated with **CTest**. Also, this creates a new problem because I'll have to run every executable, of which can be dozens, with tests separately

Comment: @AlexanderKhristosenko, it wasn't clear from your original question that there are many executable files. Indeed, it is not convenient to use add_custom_target in this case.

I would like to clarify a couple of points:

1. You need to avoid refactoring existing tests on GTest or, for example, Criterion.

2. You need to split the existing executable with tests into several, one test per executable.

It seems to me that the solution will not be simple.